# Java-- characters in list and mapping to uppercase

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am trying to convert everything in a list to uppercase, but I'm having trouble with this. I get an error for the last line:

> The method map(Function is not applicable for the
>   arguments(Character::toUppercase)

but I'm not sure how to fix it. Also, how would I display all the characters in this list that come after "g"?

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
      List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
      String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

      for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
      {
         list.add(alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(26)));
      }

     System.out.println("Ascending: ");

     list.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::print);

     System.out.println("Characters in uppercase: ");

     list.stream().map(Character::toUpperCase).collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(list.stream().map(String::valueOf).map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.joining()));` and `System.out.println(list.stream().filter(ch -> ch > 'g').map(String::valueOf).map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.joining()));`

Comment: "I get an error for the last line" - what's the error? I can't repro...

Comment: In regards to the second question: `list.subList(list.indexOf('G')+1, list.size())`

Comment: Here's the error I get: "The method map(Function<? superCharacter,? extendsR?) in the type Stream<Character> is not applicable for the arguments(Character::toUppercase) "

Comment: And for the second one, how could I do it so that the letters that come after 'g' lexicographically are shown?

Answer (score 1):

As Oleg said, your error message indicates that your compiled code referes to `getUppercase` with **c** instread of **C**. Your code example looks good and works for me. Maybe you just need to re-compile?

For filtering out the first six letters, you can just compare chars like integers:

```
Stream.of('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
          'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')
      .map(Character::toUpperCase)
      .filter(c -> c > 'G')
      .forEach(System.out::print);

// HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

you have got misspelled in your code
pls add ")" after args and also use correct method name: toUpperCase

pls check [Oracle Character docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-)